# What is the best way to fetch data from api into Redux container with Reselect in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I know this question may sounds duplicated, but I have not found any good solution on this especially in combination with [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect).

Please consider following redux container component:

```
export default connect((state, props) => {
  return {
    ...props
  }
}, (dispatch) => {
  if (shouldLoadClinic(store.getState())) {
    dispatch(loadClinicInfo())
  }

  if (shouldLoadTimezones(store.getState())) {
    dispatch(loadTimezones())
  }

  return {}
})(SettingsClinic)
```

Where eg. shouldLoadClinic() is defined like this:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

export const isClinicLoaded = ({ clinic }) => {
  return clinic.current !== null
}

export const isClinicLoading = ({ clinic }) => {
  return clinic.pending
}

export const shouldLoadClinic = createSelector([
  isClinicLoaded,
  isClinicLoading
], (isLoaded, isLoading) => {
  return !isLoaded && !isLoading
})
```

This component should make sure its child components have got all required data.
Several reasons why I don't like this solution:

1. getState() is required from the outside scope (It would be nice to have getState prop passed together with "dispatch" arg.)
2. Hard to test - in order to test if the data are loaded on mount I would have to mock store, selectors and actions.
3. Conditions - maybe call method "shouldLoadTimezonesIfNeeded()" to replace the condition would be more clean way?

Do you have any ideas? Maybe just links with the references would be enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the 3rd argument of `connect` (`mergedProps`) to have access to stateProps and dispatchProps, that way use the `selectors` inside `mapStateToProps` and then use the result in `mergedProps` - same for `dispatch`. Another way to do it, is to use the `redux-thunk` middleware, that way, you can just dispatch the actions to load every time, and check for `ifNeeded` in the `thunk`.
2. Why mock everything? you just need to mock the initial state of the store and the responses for any api requests.
3. Naming looks fine to me.

p.s: I don't really like the monkey patch you're doing in the `mapDispatchToProps`. You better always return a function for loading data, and call it inside you're component's `componentDidMount` or take care of loading data all together in a HOC.

I mean change this:

```
if (shouldLoadClinic(store.getState())) {
  dispatch(loadClinicInfo())
}
if (shouldLoadTimezones(store.getState())) {
  dispatch(loadTimezones())
}
return {}
```

Into something like this:

```
return {
  loadData: () => {
    dispatch(loadClinicInfo());
    dispatch(loadTimezones());
  }
}
```

Final note, [here](https://gist.github.com/novykh/21b607043e7a1642f96775f54f20a4eb) is a small gist for a HOC, I created, to take care of loading data and show a loader while doing it. Hope it helps.

Here is an example of connect's third argument `mergedProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({someData: selectSomeData(state)});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({dispatch})
const mergedProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps) => {
  return {
    loadData: () => stateProps.someData
      ? dispatchProps.loadData()
      : null
  }
}
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergedProps)(Component)
```

Comment: 1) Can you please show me example of third argument you talk about? That would help.

Comment: 1 - b) I dont like doing conditions in actions mainly because the condition should be in selectors which could not be used in action (recursion)
2) you are right on this one
3) I think my point was actually something else...  to wrap condition into method and replace it

Comment: @user1356619 I updated my answer to include (at the end) an example of mergedProps argument.